# How to say "you would [do that] if..."

Tags: grammar

I am trying to determine how to say the following sentence:

```
"You would go out drinking after work if you were in Japan"
```

The best I can think of is this, but it is rather matter-of-fact

```
日本でいれば　仕事のあとでビールを飲める
```

I'm not even sure if that is right!
Any thoughts?

For context, my (Japanese) friend does not want to go drinking after work (because he has a family). I want to say that if he was in Japan, he would (as it is expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

> 仕事のあとでビールを飲める

Means : you can drink after work.

What you want is :

> ビールを飲みに行くべきです。

Which would mean : You **have** to go drink a beer after work.

You might want to consider using the word お酒 instead of beer, or just drop it and say "go drink". べき will put the emphasis on the fact that he has to go if he is in Japan.

A more smooth way to express that sentence could be :

> 日本にいると、仕事が終わってから、同僚と一緒にお酒を飲みに行かないといけないですよ。

You might want to add 時々 to show that it's not everyday though.

Comment: I would advise using べき since I almost never hear it.

Comment: べき yes I vaguely remember this now. Thanks